# Is it possible to change the clone and the original element at the same time? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

I have an element with a clone inside a div parent. I want to click on **clone** and change css of this clone and its original element. But at same time if at first i click on **original** element I want to change the original elment and its clone.

Is possible ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="hello">
  Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hello {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.hello').clone().appendTo('#parent');
$('.hello').on('click',function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

Here jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vcyLkdas/

```js
$('.hello').clone().appendTo('#parent');

$('.hello').on('click',function(){
 $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

```css
.hello {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
<div class="hello">
Ciao
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `this` to `'.hello'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$(this)` with `$(".hello")` inside your handler.

```js
$(".hello").clone().appendTo("#parent");

$(".hello").on("click", function () {
  $(".hello").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```css
.hello {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="hello">
    Ciao
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In a jQuery click event, "this" refers only to the element that was clicked, not all elements of class .hello. Thus, you need to change "this" to ".hello" :

```
$('.hello').on('click',function(){
    $('.hello').css('background-color','red');
});
```